# Detecting Microphone on a Kindle Fire with Adobe AIR

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

Note: There was a similar post almost 2 years ago. It's possible that a good solution has been found since than.

I need to detect if my app is running on a Kindle Fire without a microphone, for example Kindle Fire (1st Generation). I need that information right after the app has been opened in order to adjust the user interface accordingly. I tried the following obvious approaches:

1) `Microphone.isSupported`: It's buggy and returns TRUE even for devices without a microphone.

2) `Microphone.names`: returns `AndroidMicrophone` even though there is none.

There are other approaches none of which I particularly like:

1) Listen to the microphone `ActivityEvent.ACTIVITY` or `SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA` events for a few seconds.

2) Detect Kindle device version with a custom -made ANE that would call `android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER` and `android.os.Build.MODEL`.

3) Use `funkymonkey.android.deviceinfo` to detect Kindle based on some unique combinations of device info

Do you have any suggestions on how to either detect a microphone or at least the Kindle Fire version in the most reliable way without building an ANE just for that?

Answer (score -2):

This function call does the trick:

```
PackageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_MICROPHONE);
```

Comment: Is it available in Adobe AIR?

Comment: You should rephrase your post, so it's actually an answer, and elaborate a bit more on it.

Comment: @SebastianZartner  No, not really.  Its all I feel like doing right now.  If he wants to know more he can do the research into the API, its a trivial one.  This question should have been solved by 1 google.

Comment: @nullability See same comment as above.  It is an answer, its the exact api he needs to use.

Comment: The question is specifically about detecting microphone in Adobe AIR. To the best of my knowledge, currently there is no PackageManager API in Adobe AIR.